# why meta tag Open Graph LINE social preview not woking?

Tags: line, meta-tags

I have a meta tag that works with facebook and twitter, but I want it to work with social LINE, is there any way, please help.
Thank you!

Code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09olg.png)

Evidence:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZoQE.png)

Comment: Please provide code not images. Code is more helpful than images.

Comment: please you click to [enter image description here] i don't preview image upload. sorry for this inconvenience

Comment: I have the same issue that they get the old data although I updated at prerender side